# how to get face mesh with opencv and opengl?

Tags: python, opengl, opencv

I'm using opencv and python for face detection, but I need to calculate the face position and get some features like opened eyes and opened mouth. I was thinking to use the vertex values from a face meshgrid.

Does anyone know how to get the meshgrid of a face detected with opencv?

PD: I already used Haar Cascade but it doesn't fit what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Using a HaarCascade will only return a bounding for a detected face, not a mesh. 
You should have a look at [Jason Saraigh](http://www.ri.cmu.edu/pub_files/2009/9/CameraReady-6.pdf)'s [FaceTracker](https://github.com/kylemcdonald).

I've used it in c++ alone and with [openFrameworks](https://github.com/kylemcdonald/ofxfacetracker), but I see there's a [Python wrapper](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyFaceTracker/0.1.1) available